# Remove specific child from group paperJS

Tags: javascript, paperjs

How can i remove only specific child from the group. This is my code. can anyone help.

```
    <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">

var path = new Path.Circle(new Point(80, 50), 35);
var secondPath = new Path.Circle(new Point(180, 50), 35);


var group = new Group();

group.addChild(path);
group.addChild(secondPath);


group.fillColor = 'green';


group.removeChildren();
    </script>
```

How can i remove either path or secondpath.

Answer (score 2):

Just give the path a name: http://paperjs.org/reference/path

```
var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: [80, 50],
    radius: 35
});
// Set the name of the path:
path.name = 'example';

// Create a group and add path to it as a child:
var group = new Group();
group.addChild(path);

// The path can be accessed by name:
group.children['example'].fillColor = 'red';
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the docs, you must specify either an index or index from - index to. So if you want the last one:

`group.removeChildren(group.children.length - 1);`

or first

`group.removeChildren(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Refer http://paperjs.org/reference/group/#group

pathname.remove()

example

secondpath.remove()